# How do I create random points that are a minimum distance from existing points?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am looking to generate a set of random points that are within an existing polygon, a minimum of X distance from one another, and X distance from a set of existing points.

[image: Existing Data]

My initial thoughts were that the [Create Random Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-random-points.htm) tool in ArcGIS Pro would work; however, it seems that I can only set a polygon as a constraining feature class and a minimum distance, but there is no way to incorporate the already existing points. If I use the points as a constraining feature, only a subset is selected and no new ones are created. And even if they were created, they wouldn't respect the boundaries of the polygon. My only thought is to convert the points to polygons, dissolve/merge them all together, and then use that feature as the constraining feature. If I make the "new" polygons smaller than the minimum specified distance, then I shouldn't have to worry about points being generated inside of them. Is there another way to make this work?